# returning a file stream pointer/reference from a class

Tags: c++, pointers, fstream

I am going through "Programming principles and practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I am trying to complete this exercise:

> Define a File_handle class with a constructor that takes a string argument (the file name), opens the file in the constructor, and closes it in the destructor.

I was wondering if it was possible to give the user the possibility to extract the reference/pointer to the stream to operate on it and leave to the class the responsibility to close it when out of scope.

It is probably not good practice, but I got interested in the behavior I get (see the code in `main()`), it doesn't seem possible to access the stream from outside the class, but it works perfectly inside it.

There is probably something very obvious to a trained eye that I am missing, but since I am still trying to learn, I would like to understand why and how things work a bit deeper with stream classes

Also, I would like to know how a more experienced programmer would approach the problem.

I already got similar problems a couple of times, but I couldn't find satisfying answers after a good bit of google-fu, and reading the C++ reference manual.

```cpp
class File_handle 
{
    fstream file;

    public:
    File_handle(string s)
        :file{s}
    {
        if (!file) error("File not found!");
        cerr << "Constructed File_handle" << endl;
    }

    File_handle(const File_handle&) = delete;
    File_handle& operator=(const File_handle&) = delete;

    ~File_handle()
    {
        cerr << "Destroyed File_handle" << endl;
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    
    fstream& attach() { return file; };
    fstream* attach_p() { return &file; };

    void print(ostream& os) 
    {
        while (file) {
            char c = file.get();
            cout << c;
        }
    }
};



int main() 
{

    File_handle stream {"TextFile.txt"};
    fstream& f = stream.attach();
    cout << f;      // invalid operands to binary expression
    cout << f.get();    // output => 35
    fstream* fp = stream.attach_p();
    cout << *fp;        // invalid operands to binary expression
    cout << fp->get();  // output => 35

    stream.print(cout);     // works fine, prints the whole file
    
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Possible, yes. Breaks encapsulation, though. For example,  the user could call `close` on the reference and mess up the state of the `File_handle `. In general prefer to call functions that do something to an object rather than get members from the object and operate on them independent of the object.

Comment: In order for `<<` to work, there needs to be a `<<` overload that accepts the type of the object you want to print and knows how to print it. There is no `<<` for `fstream`, but you can get the [rdbuffer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) from the stream and print it to print out the file contents. Eg: `cout << f.rdbuf();`

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why can I use the get() function inside the class returns one char and outside of it it returns an integer number (35). I can't use the << or >> operator outside the class because I get compiler error. returning a pointer to a stream is the only thing I am allowed to do for streams (there is no copy assignment or copy construction) but it seems I am missing something to make it work properly. I know this is bad practice because I am blatantly breaking encapsulation but I was curious to know why it doesn't work. I thought I might learn something new about C++.